# Short URL management software to host internal url shortening

Tags: seo

Does anyone know of any management software for hosting our own short url service for internal use?  Our marketing group wants this for Twitter and etc. so that we can push our brand.  We have both windows and linux servers where we can host.

***Addtional info:

Yes we want to do ourname.com/hkjl45 instead of going to bit.ly or tinyurl.

Answer (score 2):

Can you clarify your question slightly? As I interpret it, you are wanting a system that lets your users 'own' the shortened URL (as opposed to relying on a third party), but the shortened URLs they generate will then be tweeted?

If I've got that right, you might like these scripts, some of which I've tried - I think there are many similar ones out there though, largely Linux-based:

[Get Shorty](http://get-shorty.com/)
[Sidepath](http://thesidepath.com/news/sidepath-released-for-free)
[Yourls](http://yourls.org/)

HTH

Comment: Yes instead of going to bit.ly or tinyurl we would do ourname.com/h5bs7f

Comment: There’s also my fork, 
[Lessn More](http://lessnmore.net), which is decently popular.

Answer (score 0):

10 self-hosted URL shorteners reviewed with  their features:

- http://www.esev.com/blog/post/2009-06-host-your-own-url-shortener-10-php-apps-reviewed/

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Lessn](http://lessnmore.net/), which is open source(if you care).

Comment: A benefit of using this instead of a bit.ly with a custom domain: You get shorter URLs and no custom URLs/slugs have been taken. (bit.ly uses the same pool of slugs across all domains.)